Is there a way to tell whether Date.parse() acted on its own?
I am currently building a database of old Usenet postings (spanning from 1988 to 1999) from which I want to extract the respective time stamps. As expected, there were a lot of non-standard date strings in use at the time. Nonetheless, the Date.parse() method offers promising results, although it handles time zones in a rather idiosyncratic way.
Let's review the cases of interest:

If the string contains (in whichever form) valid date, time, and time zone information, there obviously is no problem.
E.g. "8 Aug 93 02:49:00 PDT" will be interpreted as (JSON-style) 1993-08-08T09:49:00Z.

If the string does not contain valid information at all, and hence, cannot be parsed, Date.parse() returns NaN, which, again, is fine.

However, if the string contains valid date and time information, but no time zone information, Date.parse() acts on its own and assumes local time zone.
E.g. "8 Aug 93 02:49:00" will be interpreted as 1993-08-08T00:49:00Z because I'm currently in the CEST, or UTC+2, time zone.

Moreover, if the string contains valid date, but no time information, Date.parse(), again, acts on its own, albeit differently this time, by assuming UTC.
E.g. "8 Aug 93" will be interpreted as 1993-08-07T22:00:00Z, again, because I'm currently in the CEST time zone.


Cases 3 and 4 constitute a major problem for the task at hand, because the resulting Date object will be indistinguishable from one obtained by parsing a completely specified string. For instance, "8 Aug 93 02:49:00" (case 3) will be interpreted the same as "8 Aug 93 00:49:00 GMT" — but only in the time zone the program is currently running in! Or, "8 Aug 93" (case 4) will, in the end, be indistinguishable from "8 Aug 93 00:00:00 GMT+2" (again, assuming CEST).
So my question is: Can Date.parse() be forced to tell the programmer whether, and if so which, assumptions it made during the parsing process?
Ideally, I want to be able to review incomplete information myself, and possibly correct it, based on otherwise available information. For instance, if the original text was posted in the month of August, from a server of the University of Washington, then the time zone should be PDT – and not my current, local one; nor UTC.

Firstly: everything you described is clearly documented. That said, what's stopping you from inspecting the value your code is attempting to parse as a Date BEFORE trying to parse it? it's easy to see what Date.parse will do with the string you are supplying to the function - if the original text was posted in the month of August, from a server of the University of Washington, then the time zone should be PDT Date.parse has no knowledge of this, it's up to your code to manage this aspect

I'm obviously not asking for Date.parse() to do something it cannot possibly do. All I'm asking is this: If Date.parse() is able to supply information on its own, then it should also be able to indicate whether it actually did so or not. This would sieve out all fully-specified strings and leave only the special cases to be handled in a second phase.

it should also be able to but it doesn't, however, it's a trivial test by your code to determine what it does - you seem to have glossed over that part of my comment

Not at all. What's stopping you from inspecting the value your code is attempting to parse as a Date BEFORE trying to parse it? The fact that each case will be different and, therefore, has to be inspected manually.

yes, that is correct - you're already scrapping each case, so a little trivial code to determine how dat.parse will handle the date you scrapped isnt too much effort at all

What you suggest basically amounts to reproducing the source code of Date.parse(). I precisely intended the Date.parse() method to do the sieving “en passant”, so to speak.

No, it doesn't. anyway this statement If the string contains (in whichever form) valid date, time, and time zone information, there obviously is no problem. is patently wrong. Date.parse basically knows UTC, GMT, and American (the U.S. type, not all american) time zones ... anything else, you're on your own - I'd recommend using a date library, but I won't recommend which one

Valid from the perspective of Date.parse(), of course. I would be fine with handling the exceptions you mention.
I'd recommend using a date library, but I won't recommend which one. What's the point of saying this?

because recommending libraries is off topic, and I'm not sure which one would suit your needs ... date-fns, luxon, days.js, temporal  are some that I know

I see, thank you, I will have a look at each of them.

There is no direct of identifying dates from different timezones without timezone details. Get the timezone from the location or zip code details if you have them in your database, add missing timezones to the timestamps, and convert all those timestamps to a common timezone, preferably UTC, using Date.parse() to output the UNIX format timestamp or using the Intl.DateTimeFormat API.

"Can Date.parse() be forced to tell the programmer whether, and if so which, assumptions it made during the parsing process?" No. Beyond the 3 formats required to be parsed correctly, parsing is implementation dependent and varies between them, even between different versions of the same implementation.


Can Date.parse() be forced to tell the programmer whether, and if so which, assumptions it made during the parsing process?

No. There's many date libraries out there that give you full control over parsing though.
